# Multiple threads call the same function with different set of argument values

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am learning multithreading in C++ in which I wrote a simple program where multiple threads call the same function . At each function call, I am passing different argument values.

Below is the program with output snippet.

```
void add(int x,int y) {
  int sum = x + y;
  cout<<sum<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  vector<thread> th;

  for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
     a=i;
     b=i+1;
     th.push_back(thread(add,a,b));
  }
       
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    th[i].join();
}
```

Maximum sum should be 201 but in output but one entry is showing 713. This might be as threads run independently and so the results are random.
Output :

```
31

19
11
713
9
5

21
...
```

I want to know that how can I obtain its output in sequence.

As each thread creates its own call stack and local function variables for the same function called by different threads are unique, so, I think in this case mutex lock is not required as each thread is executing the code in its own address space, they are not sharing any variable. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Also, please suggest some resources (ebooks, courses etc.) to learn basics of multithreading in C++.

Comment: All of your threads are accessing the same `cout` object, so their output can get mixed together.  For example, `713` might be one thread outputting `7` and another thread outputting `13` at around the same time.  If you want to ensure that your threads don't step on each others' output, you should have a mutex and have each thread lock it before using `cout` and unlock it afterward.

Comment: Are you looking to get the results printed in the order the thread was created, or just ensure that the output is distinct per thread?

Comment: @Alan Both, I am trying to grasp the concept of multithreading

Comment: @JeremyFriesner change the code as you suggested but still output got mixed as before

Comment: Are your threads all locking *the same* mutex?  If they are each locking a different mutex then they won’t be synchronized with each other.

Comment: @JeremyFriesne ya Thanks, now I can see the output as expected. One more thing, if there isn't any cout object which is shared, only sum , a and b variables then I think I don't need mutex to synchronize as they are local variables to a thread. Am I right? Also, if I pass a and b as reference then also I don't need mutex to sync.

Comment: No shared objects mean no potential race conditions means no need to sync/serialize access to anything.  Note however that if you pass a and b in as references, and they are referring to the same variables in multiple threads, then you're back to sharing state across threads again, and you'd need to use a mutex to serialize access to `a` and `b` (or at least declare `a` and `b` as `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int`, so that unsynchronized accesses to them can still be well-defined)

Answer (score 1):

713 is 7 and 13.
Try

```
void add(int x,int y) {
  int sum = x + y;
  cout<< std::to_string(sum) + "\n";
}
```

You should use a mutex to exclusively access std::cout.

Comment: How do we know it's not 71 and 3?

Comment: Or it could be `7`, `1`, and `3`, or anything else.  Once you've invoked undefined behavior, almost anything is possible :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think 1 and 3 are already spent on the first output line :-)